# What do setUseWideViewPort() and setLoadWithOverviewMode() precisely do?

Tags: android, webview, webkit

I am disappointed at the lack of documentation of WebView and related stuff.

(unless you think the following is propert documetation)

> public void setLoadWithOverviewMode
>   (boolean overview)
>
> Set whether the
>   WebView loads a page with overview
>   mode

and:

> public synchronized void setUseWideViewPort (boolean use)
>
> Tell the WebView to use the wide viewport

So: **What is "Overview mode" ? what is "Wide viewport" ?**

ps: I tried to look for webkit related docs but could not find it.

Comment: Completely agree with you.
As far as I understand overview viewport is something like you zoom out 100% that you get an "overiew".
What wide viewport does i don't know, only that it enables double tap zooming.

Comment: I agree! Joker documentation!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Apparently:

**setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)** loads the WebView completely zoomed out

**setUseWideViewPort(true)** makes the Webview have a normal viewport (such as a normal desktop browser), while when false the webview will have a viewport constrained to its own dimensions (so if the webview is 50px*50px the viewport will be the same size)

Comment: Is `setUseWideViewPort(true)` similar or even identical to what web browsers apps have, when you click on "desktop site" ? Or is it a bit more complex?

Comment: I think it needs more. Maybe user-agent?

Answer (score 9):

If the setUseWideViewPort(true), it loads the WebView with the attributes defined in the meta tag of the webpage. So it scales the webpage as defined in the html.

Answer (score 7):

From ["Web Page Layout"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/web-page-layout.md) documentation of WebView,

[image: Web Page Layout]