# Android: Is it possible and how to change the fontsize of a HTML page displayed in a WebView?

Tags: android, html, webview, font-size

Is it possible and how to change the fontsize of a HTML page displayed in a WebView? Similiar as in a desktop browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);
```

This one also works:-

```
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(15);
```

This may help you .

For more information take a look

[How to change the FontSize in an Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/android-webview-font-size-change)

OR
[WebView text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573666/webview-text-size)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try any of these.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);
```

OR

```
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(10);
```