# Android webview not scrolling

Tags: android, webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple2" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/text98"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA Code:**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.text98);
// mWebView.setMinimumHeight(height);
// mWebView.setMinimumWidth(width);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new DefaultWebViewClient() );
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

What could the reason be? Why is scrolling not working? it works at times, but at certain other times no? Thank you for all the hellp, appreciated.Adding more lines because i am not able to get past by more code lines then post.

Comment: added my java code

Comment: Is there a reason you wrap your WebView in LinearLayout? Is seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why don't you use `ScrollView`?

Comment: all solutions tried, they dont work.

Comment: Did you put `meta` `viewport` tag into your html page?

Comment: It is maybe web page problem (if the page formed using JS and HTML page has no scroll part). I have the same problem earlier.

Comment: Try : android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your linear layout

Comment: wrap conten did not work.

Comment: One thing i add, the page has overflow for scrolling. html  code. if i remove the overflow, it stops working on my chrome. so the issue is definetly the android webview not detecting overflow?

Answer (score 0):

[`Nested Scrolling`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) : If [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) is nested to a scrolling parent ( like [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) ), it can't scroll properly. Disable [`Nested Scrolling`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) with :

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

---

[`Overlapping Views`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android) : On top [`Overlapping Views`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android) in [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) prevent scrolling. There should be no views in [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView), if so, adjust their `layout`.

Check `.xml` file and make sure [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) is not covered & overlapped by any other view.

---

[`WebView Size`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) : If [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) size is too small, you can't scroll. Check the `height` and `width` to display content and scroll.

If the content is too large from [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) you have to adjust, scale or zoom the settings.

---

[`WebView Settings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings) : You've may been disabled the scroll function from settings. Enable it calling:

```
webView.getSettings().setScrollEnabled(true)
```

You also have the possibility to enable various settings like : [`setBuiltInZoomControls`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings), [`setDisplayZoomControls`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings) and [`setSupportZoom`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings).

---

[`Content Size`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) : If [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) content is either too large or too small, scrolling can't work. The content needs to fit in [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) and have to adjust the scaling.

You also have the possibility to use methods like : [`setLoadWithOverviewMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448841/what-do-setusewideviewport-and-setloadwithoverviewmode-precisely-do) & [`setUseWideViewPort`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448841/what-do-setusewideviewport-and-setloadwithoverviewmode-precisely-do).

---

[`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) : You have to set a [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) for [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) because it can affect the scrolling. Set a [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) by calling [`setWebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) in the instance.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than adding all the features of WebView, try adding the following code and it should work

In onCreate(),

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
```

And then,

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope, this resolves your issue...